# Removing all statements from the top line of a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

**Basic mechanics question.**  In the `for loop` below I moved the first and 3rd loop statements from their normal position.  var `i=1` is above the loop and `i++` is positioned inside the loop. Everything runs fine.  However I've read that a `for loop` can also run fine with the 2nd statement "`i > 10`" removed.  Where can the second statement sit besides it's default position inside the parenthesis?  Would the for loop look like `for (;;;)` ?

```
var i=1;
for (; i > 10;) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the for loop would look like `for(;;;)`. The second statement `i < 10` could sit inside of an `if` block inside the `for` loop. If the condition is satisfied, you break out of the loop. Although I don't know why you'd want to do it this way. `i > 10` would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: The `i > 10` condition of your loop would cause it to never run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed

```
var i = 1;
for (;;) {
  if(i > 10) break;
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Your increment is in the wrong spot to emulate the original behavior.

Comment: @squint Is it? I will fix it then. my bad :)

Answer (score 3):

A `for` loop with no parameter would look like this: `for(;;)`.

It is basically equal to `while(true)`, therefore it will be run infinitely or stop if the keyword `break` is used.

You can try this out:

```
for(;;) {
    alert("infinite loop");
}
```

You will see that the alerts do not stop.